# How can I create an Azure Blob Container/Table by Azure Resource Manager template

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I knew that we can create an Azure Storage Account by Azure Resource Manager template. See [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-storage-account-create) template.

Question: Can I create an Azure Blob Container/ Table inside a storage account by Azure Resource Manager template and how to do that?

Comment: I also suggest going [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/9306108-let-me-define-preconfigured-blob-containers-table) and voting for this feedback item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: Can I create an Azure Blob Container/ Table inside a storage
>   account by Azure Resource Manager template and how to do that?

Simple answer is that no you can't (at least as of today).

In order to create a Blob Container or Table inside a Storage Account you would need to use `Storage REST API` whereas template deployment works off of `Azure Resource Manager API`.